# Laplace transform of some functions

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

What would be the Laplace transform of these functions?

\$f(t) = [5u(t)]^{2} - u(t)\$

\$f(t) = tu(2t)\$

As for the first function, it is like multiplying two unit step functions which is not convolution.

In the second function, there is frequency scaling but it may not matter for the unit step function so it seems that \$u(2t)\$is same as  \$u(t)\$  whose laplace transform is \$\frac{1}{s}\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint_A**: The square of a unit step \$[u(t)]^2\$ is just the unit step \$u(t)\$.

**Hint_B**: \$u(2t)\$ is also a unit step and \$t ⋅u(t)\$ is the ramp function, \$t\$ for \$t\geq 0\$.

Comment: I believe I have written the solution then. Thanks.